# no line break between button and form

Tags: html, forms, button

How do I get a button and a form element in the same line without a linebreak happening? 
thank you very much!

```
  <button>ask question</button>
<form action="/search" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="q" value="{SearchQuery}"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use this CSS style: `style="display: inline;"` on your form.

```
<form action="/search" method="get" style="display: inline;">
```

Here's a [demo on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/odolop/edit#javascript,html).

Answer (score 4):

both `<button>` and `<form>` are block level elements. you'd need to make them inline with CSS `display: inline`. not sure if that's what you mean. also it depends on your broader HTML.

Answer (score 4):

You could make the button a float:

```
<button style="float: left;">ask question</button>
```

Comment: This also works for a form, while the accepted answer did not work.

Answer (score 3):

Input fields are block-level elements. You can change the display rules in CSS:

```
input { display: inline; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can float: left both the button and the form

Answer (score 1):

For adding new line after input box then `add -> input { display: block; }` in your css file